# Using formula in a fillable PDF forms made with LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, javascript

I used the `hyperref` LaTeX package to make fillable PDFs in order to evaluate student's works. It's a lists of boxes in which notes are given, with :
`\TexField[name=note1,value=0,width=33pt,height=12p]{}` (in a `Form` environment)

Now, I want to add a last box where the values of the preceding ones would be automatically summed, as in an LibreOffice or Excel Spreadsheet.
It seems this could be achievable with JavaScript commands, like explained on [this (french) blog](https://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/creer-des-formulaire-pdf-editables). I'm not familiar with JavaScript langage, but I try this :

```
\PushButton[name=go,calculate={var a=this.getField("note1"); var b=this.getField("note2"); var c=this.getField("note3") etc...;
var Total=this.getField("Total"); Total.value=(a.value+b.value+c.value...)}]{Get sum}
\TextField[name=Total,width=33pt,height=12pt,value=''Total''.value,readonly=true]{}
```

But the sum never appears in the last box. It seems that the `getField` instruction doesn't work, or that I don't have the right way to display the result.

Could someone says what's wrong, or give me another trick to obtain the expected result ?

Here the example found on the blog I've cited :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \TextField[name=nb1,value=0]{Valeur numero 1}\\
  \TextField[name=nb2,value=0]{Valeur numero 2}\\
  \TextField[name=moy]{Moyenne des deux}\\
  \PushButton[name=go,
              onclick={var a = this.getField("nb1");var b=this.getField("nb2");
                       var moy=this.getField("moy");moy.value=(a.value+b.value)/2
                       }
              ]{Calculate}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

When I add a value to the nb1 or nb2 boxes, the mean value (moy) is not calculated.

Thanks a lot,

Cyril

Comment: don't show only snippets, but a complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: OK. Here is the exemple found on the blog I've cited : ```\begin{Form}
  \TextField[name=nb1,value=0]{Valeur numero 1}\\
  \TextField[name=nb2,value=0]{Valeur numero 2}\\
  \TextField[name=moy]{Moyenne des deux}\\
  \PushButton[name=go,
              onclick={var a = this.getField("nb1");var b=this.getField("nb2");
                       var moy=this.getField("moy");moy.value=(a.value+b.value)/2
                       }
              ]{Cliquez ici pour calculer}
\end{Form}```When I add a value to the nb1 or nb2 boxes, the mean value (moy) is not calculated.

Comment: That is not a complete example, it doesn't start with \documentclass. Also don't add it in the comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: works fine, are you using a pdfviewer which can handle javascript? E.g. adobe reader? Side remark: with a current latex you don't need to load inputenc and textcomp, both is already included.

Comment: Yes, I use Acrobat reader as pdfviewer. But for me it doesn't work. It could be due to another package, but I don't know which one cause the problem.

Comment: How can another package interfere? Is your example a fake? Didn't you try it?

Comment: It seems I have a problem with the correct attribution of labels to the various fields, so the sum cannot be done properly...

Comment: look your example above worked perfectly for me. If *this* example fails for you you should show screenshot what you get, and also the log-file. If some *other* example fails for you don't expect me to guess what you are doing, show this other example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. I found the problem, it was due to bad labelling of the various fields I tried to sum. With correct labels, it works. It could even be automated with the help of this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724045/adobe-pdf-forms-javascript-sum-values-from-different-fields Thanks for your help.